# MS SQL return single row case dataset without GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data set of ActivityDate which is a datetime field and EngineHours which is a decimal field. I want to return a single row of data that brings back the average number of EngineHours on each day of the week. The dataset is pretty big so the best performance is likely to be the most ideal, the script below doesn't work because ActivityDate is not contained in either an aggregate or GROUP BY clause:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, CS.ActivityDate) = 'Monday' THEN AVG(CS.EngineHours) END AS MondayEngineHours,
    CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, CS.ActivityDate) = 'Tuesday' THEN AVG(CS.EngineHours) END AS TuesdayEngineHours,
    CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, CS.ActivityDate) = 'Wednesday' THEN AVG(CS.EngineHours) END AS WednesdayEngineHours,
    CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, CS.ActivityDate) = 'Thursday' THEN AVG(CS.EngineHours) END AS ThursdayEngineHours,
    CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, CS.ActivityDate) = 'Friday' THEN AVG(CS.EngineHours) END AS FridayEngineHours,
    CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, CS.ActivityDate) = 'Saturday' THEN AVG(CS.EngineHours) END AS SaturdayEngineHours,
    CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, CS.ActivityDate) = 'Sunday' THEN AVG(CS.EngineHours) END AS SundayEngineHours
FROM 
    CustomerSummary CS WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE
    ActivityDate >= '2021-02-01'
AND
    ActivityDate <= '2021-02-07'
```

Comment: The whole `CASE` should be inside the aggregate, not just the `THEN`. Also, do you really "need" the `NOLOCK`?

Comment: Thanks for your input on the question, please can you keep to the question at hand in future - the NOLOCK was not part of the question.

Comment: I humbly will never do that; if I see something that is wrong in a question, I will address it. Just like if I saw a question that contain a huge security flaw, I'm not going to ignore it because it's a problem. I addressed both your question, and the another potential flaw in your existing attempt. If you don't like people improving your attempts, then the reflection should only be your own; don't shoot down the good faith of other users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close.  The `CASE` is the argument to the `AVG()`:

```
SELECT AVG(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, CS.ActivityDate) = 'Monday' THEN CS.EngineHours END) AS MondayEngineHours,
       AVG(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, CS.ActivityDate) = 'Tuesday' THEN CS.EngineHours END) AS TuesdayEngineHours,
       AVG(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, CS.ActivityDate) = 'Wednesday' THEN CS.EngineHours END) AS WednesdayEngineHours,
       AVG(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, CS.ActivityDate) = 'Thursday' THEN CS.EngineHours END) AS ThursdayEngineHours,
       AVG(CASE WHEN DATENAM)E(dw, CS.ActivityDate) = 'Friday' THEN CS.EngineHours END AS FridayEngineHours,
       AVG(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, CS.ActivityDate) = 'Saturday' THEN CS.EngineHours END) AS SaturdayEngineHours,
       AVG(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, CS.ActivityDate) = 'Sunday' THEN CS.EngineHours END) AS SundayEngineHours
FROM CustomerSummary CS
WHERE ActivityDate >= '2021-02-01' AND
      ActivityDate <= '2021-02-07'
```

Answer (score 2):

The aggregation function must wrap the case

```sql
         SELECT 
            AVG(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, CS.ActivityDate) = 'Monday' THEN CS.EngineHours END AS MondayEngineHours,
            AVG(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, CS.ActivityDate) = 'Tuesday' THEN CS.EngineHours EN)D AS TuesdayEngineHours,
            AVG(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, CS.ActivityDate) = 'Wednesday' THEN CS.EngineHours E)ND AS WednesdayEngineHours,
           AVG( CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, CS.ActivityDate) = 'Thursday' THEN CS.EngineHours END )AS ThursdayEngineHours,
           AVG( CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, CS.ActivityDate) = 'Friday' THEN CS.EngineHours END A)S FridayEngineHours,
           AVG( CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, CS.ActivityDate) = 'Saturday' THEN CS.EngineHours E)ND AS SaturdayEngineHours,
           AVG( CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, CS.ActivityDate) = 'Sunday' THEN CS.EngineHours END A)S SundayEngineHours
        FROM )
            CustomerSummary CS WITH(NOLOCK)
        WHERE
            ActivityDate >= '2021-02-01'
        AND
            ActivityDate <= '2021-02-07'
```